# laravel artisan unexpected error php 5.4.3

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, but have been studying few things. I am following a tutorial to start my new site. It provided migrations generated through generator.

But when I try to execute the migrations by calling php artisan migrate on command line, I get the following message:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\root\site\app\routes.php on line 7

I got the same message on site home page and by googling I figured I need to upgrade php version to at least 5.4 to get this working. I upgraded to PHP 5.4.3 and it worked. However, in case of artisan I still get the above error on command prompt window.

Can it be because I upgraded over existing WAMP installation? or can anyone please give me an idea? I would confirm that php version is 5.4.3 and php is running fine on my machine.

Comment: Well error you got before is indeed related to <5.4 since in php 5.4 it was introduced that kind of array syntax. When you do ``php -v`` is it reporting with 5.4.x version or old 5.3? In any case laravel works with >= 5.3.7 php version. Any problems you might have are because of tutorials contents or directly related to WAMP <> Laravel setup.

Comment: Oh yes, it says 5.3.8 (checked on command prompt window), while phpinfo says it is 5.4.3 (checked in browser). Do you have an idea, what can be the reason?

Comment: Actually here's all steps for this kind of manipulation - http://www.websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp#.UzlIy_mPGQA

Comment: Thanks arma. I am looking into these. I will take some time, as I am not familier with this kind of update. I will share the updates

Comment: Sure, just post here back. Generally what the idea - each php mode has it's own php.ini file and also PATH in your windows environment needs an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help above by arma. My problem is now resolved.

The reason errors on browser were gone was that it was using php 5.4.3 and the format of code was supported in php versions greater than 5.4 only. But Command Line version of php was still 5.3.8. I previously upgraded version of php by upgrading wamp, so that was also existing. Typing php -v gave me the version I had on command line.

I updated windows path variable and php versions in few of the ini and conf files to update the command line version of the php.

Following URL can help: http://www.websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp#.UzlpBIUw2JB. After setting up the PHP version for CLI to 5.4.3 Migrations ran successfully for me.